# WOPI Host not called

Tags: ms-wopi

I would like to know why is my WOPI Host not being called. I launch my host through an HTML page similar to:

```
https://github.com/Microsoft/Office-Online-Test-Tools-and-Documentation/blob/master/samples/SampleHostPage.html
```

For the testing purposes I am handling just one file.

The discovery file I am using:

```
https://onenote.officeapps-df.live.com/hosting/discovery
```

Link for viewing word file:

```xml
<form id="office_form" name="office_form" target="office_frame"
  action="https://word-view.officeapps-df.live.com/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?ui=nb-NO&rs=nb-NO&dchat=1&IsLicensedUser=1&WOPISrc=http%3A%2F%2F138.68.127.245%3A8082%2Fcontext%2Fwopi%2Ffiles%2Fxyz" method="post">
  <input name="access_token" value="something" type="hidden"/>
  <input name="access_token_ttl" value="0" type="hidden"/>
</form>
```

Any help appreciated! 
Of course my server is available at the time I am writing this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to be a member of the [Office 365 Cloud Storage Partner Program](http://dev.office.com/programs/officecloudstorage) to be able to use the [MS discovery URLs](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/environments.html#wopi-discovery-urls) and the WOPI clients in general. Your domain has to be added to the [WOPI domain allow list](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/settings.html#allow-list) (a list of trusted domains), this can only be done by Microsoft.

If you are not a member of that program, you can host a WOPI client on your own. You can choose between the Office Online Server 2016 and Office Web Apps 2013. Both are available through MSDN.

Comment: Contact Microsoft via the **CSPP Yammer group** to request changes to your domain entries. :: https://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/domains.html

Comment: I am part of CSPP, where do I get access_token and access_token_ttl values? Also, can I send csv file to have it open on host frame?