# From where may I get the WOPI Client discovery XML for the WOPI client Office Online / Office Web Apps?

Tags: ms-office, office365, office-interop, office-js, ms-wopi

What's the URL from where I (the WOPI host/server I am writing) may download the client discovery XML file from for the WOPI client Office Online / Office Web Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter whether you're using Office Web Apps 2013, Office Online Server 2016, or [Office Online 365](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/environments.html), the URL is always in the following form: `http://<owaserver>/hosting/discovery`

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's the `owaserver` part I don't know. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I mean for the Office Online that Microsoft has made, and not for an internal deployment of Office Web Apps. I would like to use the Office Online WOPI client.

Comment: The link's already in the answer, if you click [Office Online](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_test_ship/environments.html)

Comment: But you need to be a cloud storage partner to be able to use Office Online. See my other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772584/wopi-host-not-called/39789525#39789525